# Email/password login in yii2

Tags: yii2

Is that possible to use yii2 login and rbac with email/password instead of username/password? my custom wo_user table does not contains username field, instead, it contains wo_email and wo_password.

Comment: you need to update the `login()` method for the in the `LoginForm` model probably but cant be specific until you add the relevant models that you are using.

Comment: thank you @MuhammadOmerAslam for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Add **findByEmail()** function in your **User** model

```
public static function findByEmail($email){
    return static::find()->where(['wo_email' => $email, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE])->one();
}
```

**2)** Change  **rules()** and **getUser()** functions in **LoginForm** model

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['wo_email', 'wo_password'], 'required'],
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            ['wo_password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

protected function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === null) {
            $this->_user = User::findByEmail($this->wo_email);
        }
        return $this->_user;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you FeR-S, I will try this.

Comment: @AhmadZahabi Ok, let me know about result please.

Comment: I would notice the programmers that I use the code below to show the first name and  last name of the user:                                                               
$user= Yii::$app->user->identity->findIdentity(Yii::$app->user->id); 
echo $user->wo_firstName;

Comment: And should replace the user identity class name in backend/config/main.php                                                                   'user' => [                                                                                                                 
             'identityClass' => 'app\models\WoUser',
            ...]